# Translation of sign 和福佳生活馆

Tags: translation

How would you put 和福佳生活馆 in English?  (or Spanish)

Background: There was a place near me with a sign in Chinese and English.  The sign is no longer there, and the current occupant is a Chinese restaurant.  Someone there told me that the previous occupant was also a Chinese restaurant.  But the English on it—*[Something]* Life House—doesn’t seem like a name for a restaurant.  So I tried to translate the Chinese myself and couldn’t.  So I cropped out the English and used OCR to get text I could send to a translator.  But neither DeepL nor Google was able to translate the first half.  Google gives "Hefujia Life Museum" and Deep gives "Hofujia LIVING HALL."  The original English ended with "Life House" but I don't remember the "something" on what I cropped out (I didn't save the original image).  I do remember that it was an English word.

**So, I'd like a translation of 和福佳生活馆.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**和福佳 is the name of the place, the question is "what 生活馆 is about?"**

**From Biadu** (https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/1550194915637875267.html):

生活馆是提供美容、美发、美体、健身、护肤、香熏等扮靓服务，售卖服饰、包包等时尚物品的场所。 **生活馆是生活方式的一种体验**。 生活馆有两类，一类是提供某种功能性服务端场所，如：养生、保健、美容等；另外一种是体验式营销场所，如家居生活馆、布艺生活馆、

**Google Translation**:

The **Living Hall (生活馆)** is a place that provides beauty, hairdressing, body beautification, fitness, skincare, aromatherapy, and other dressing services, and sells fashionable items such as clothing and bags. **The Living Hall is an experience of the lifestyle**. There are two types of living halls, one is to provide a certain functional service end place, such as health, health care, beauty, etc.; The other is experiential marketing places, such as **homeliving life hall**, **fabric art life hall**.

Depending on its service nature, 和福佳生活馆 can either be simply translated as "和福佳 Living (experience) hall/house/place, or more precisely as "和福佳 xx Life hall".

Comment: OK, I wish I could remember what _single_ English word they used for 和福佳.  But at least now I know that the person who told me it was a restaurant was wrong.

Comment: @伟思礼 I wouldn't say the person was wrong without knowing the services the place provides. A restaurant that provides and promotes healthy food as a living style may be qualified to name itself xx生活馆.

Answer (score 2):

和福佳 seems to be a name, therefore using the transliteration "He Fujia" instead of the literal translation "和(Peace), 福(fortune), 佳(excellence)" is the standard practice

和福佳生活馆 can be transliterated + translated as "House of He Fuji life " or literally transliterated as "House of Peaceful, Happy, and Excellent Life"